# Global variable does not update?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Global variable does not update but I import it to interpreter it is updating.

Please help me how to update dictionary `d`

```
import texttable

class Lc:

    d={50:8,100:6,200:4,500:3,1000:2,2000:1}
    he=['container_size_in_ltrs','qty']
    def inventory(self,g):
        d1=self.d
        if d1!=g:
            d1=g
        self.d=g
        l1=d1.keys()
        l1.sort()
        li=[]
        ls=[]
        for i in l1:
            li=[]
            li.append(i)
            li.append(d1[i])
            ls.append(li)
        table=texttable.Texttable()
        table.header(self.he)
        table.add_rows(ls,header=False)
        print table.draw()

    def add_inv(self,k,v):
        d=self.d
        for i,j in d.items():
            if k==i:
                d[k]=d[k]+v
        print d
        return d

z=Lc()

g=z.add_inv(500,2)

print z.d
```

Comment: d is not a member of `LC`. do `self.d` instead. same for the other variables you want to access like `z.d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your global variable is updating.  Taking a subset of your code:

```
class Lc:

    d={50:8,100:6,200:4,500:3,1000:2,2000:1}
    he=['container_size_in_ltrs','qty']

    def add_inv(self,k,v):
        d=self.d
        for i,j in d.items():
            if k==i:
                d[k]=d[k]+v
        print d
        return d

z=Lc()
x=Lc()

print "Add 2 to 500, expect 500:5"
g=z.add_inv(500,2)
print z.d

# Notice that x.add_inv also modifies z.d
print "Add 5 to 500, expect 500:7 because x initialized d again"
h=x.add_inv(500,2)
print z.d
```

I get:

```
Add 2 to 500, expect 500:5
{100: 6, 200: 4, 2000: 1, 1000: 2, 50: 8, 500: 5}
{100: 6, 200: 4, 2000: 1, 1000: 2, 50: 8, 500: 5}
Add 5 to 500, expect 500:7 because x initialized d again
{100: 6, 200: 4, 2000: 1, 1000: 2, 50: 8, 500: 7}
{100: 6, 200: 4, 2000: 1, 1000: 2, 50: 8, 500: 7}
```

I just hope that you are indeed trying to declare `d` as global in this pelicular way.